# What font is CourierLatin1

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, courier

I have a pdf I need to, using Acrobat Professional, change a few characters in. The problem is that when I do I get an error message that the font is not available. Viewing properties for these characters reveals that the font is called CourierLatin1. Googling for this does not reveal any definitive answer but it might be an IBM mainframe/mini computer system font (Would not be surprising, the origin of the file is probably some old system like that. The file is generated by ClipPDF Library 2.02-r1-2.)

I have tried editing the file on both Mac OS X and Windows 7 but their built in versions of Courier but it is not right. I also downloaded and converted the Courier variant that is included with X.org. It was better but still not a perfect match.

How can I determine the exact variation of the Courier used? And is the IBM version available for download somewhere?

Comment: Courier Latin1 can be found in the IBM z/OS font collection topic [Summary table for the General Library fonts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.e0zx100/e0z2o00_excore_zos.htm) .

Comment: @AdamLimbert Thank you. Do you know if I can download these fonts somewhere?

Comment: They appear to come with the operating system, but I'm not sure that will help you much. I had wondered if they come with [IBM SoftCopy Reader](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018849) but my initial investigations came up with nothing. Maybe with one of the other [BookManager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018857) products?